# Pass variable to class for use by __init__

Tags: python

I've a class

```
class Container(ContainerApp):
    def __init__(self, config,
                 image=None,
                 dns='a.b.c',
                 image_path=None,
                 ip=None):
    ...
```

It is used in the config of another class as follows:

```py
class BasicTest(TestInterface):

    config = {
                'timeout': 1000,
                'api': MyAPI,
                'notification': Container,
    }
    ...
```

I want to pass an `ip` to be used by the `Container` class. I tried `'notification': Container(device_ip='1.1.1.1')` in my config but it give me this error:

```
line 1650, in BasicTest
    'notification': Container(ip='1.1.1.1'),
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

How do I do this?

Comment: You're not giving it a `config`, only an `ip`

Comment: You want `config['notification']` to be a *callable* that, when called, returns an instance of `Container` with the value of `ip` set to something that you want to "bind" beforehand…?! I.e. you'll do `config['notification'](config)` yourself later on at some point…?

Comment: `config` parameter doesn't have a default value, so it always needs to be passed when creating a `Container`.

Comment: Oh, I just realised that `config` in `Container` and `config` in `BasicTest` are not the same thing. Althought my error seems to stem fro mthe fact that `Container` expects a `config` argument to be passed for `config` but with `Container(device_ip='1.1.1.1')` I'm not doing that. Perhaps I should default `config` in `Container` to `None`. Does this seem like a resonable option?

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the best solution, but it's doable this way:

```
config = {
    'timeout': 1000,
    'api': MyAPI,
#    'notification': Container,
}
config['notification'] = Container(config, ip='1.1.1.1')
```

Assuming that "this" `config` (in `BasicTest`) is meant to be "that" `config` (passed to `Container()`) too, and the question is the "recursion".

Comment: Hey there, sexy… 

Comment: Well, I'm not a girl, so you haven't seduced any yet. Still on track.

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines that you want `config['notification']` to be a *type* instead of an instance, i.e. that you will later instantiate it yourself, but you want to provide a default value for the `ip` parameter already:

```
from functools import partial

...

config = {
    'notification': partial(Container, ip='1.1.1.1')
}
```

An alternative would be `lambda *args, **kwargs: Container(*args, ip='1.1.1.1', **kwargs)`, which is essentially what `partial` papers over very nicely.

In other words, you want `config['notification']` to be a *callable* (e.g. a function), which, when called, returns an instance of `Container` with a predefined value for one of its arguments.